# Unable to use Objective-C library in Swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've just tried to import Objective-C library named [DDHotKey](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey) in Swift project and it doesn't work in some cases.

Here are the steps I've done:

- Download "DDHotKey" repository
- Right-click on the project -> "Add files to %project_name%" -> Select "DDHotKey-master" folder with "Copy items if needed" checkbox and "Create folder references" radiobutton enabled
- According to the Apple documentation, prompt about the bridging header should appear then, but it didn'tt-- files just copied to the project's directory
- I've tried to add bridging header to the project manually (File -> New -> Source -> Header file) with the name "bridge.h", set it in the project's settings (Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header -> "bridge.h") and place the following code to this file:

.

```
#ifndef project_name_bridge_h
#define project_name_bridge_h

#import "DDHotKey-master/DDHotKeyCenter.h"

#endif
```

Now it compiles the following code:

```
var hotKeyCenter = DDHotKeyCenter.sharedHotKeyCenter()
```

But when I tried to call method of this object I've got an error:

```
hotKeyCenter.registerHotKeyWithKeyCode(34, modifierFlags: 0, task: (NSEvent) {
    println("str")
})
```

> Missing argument for parameter 'action' in call

though there are two methods and I use the different one:

```
- (DDHotKey *)registerHotKeyWithKeyCode:(unsigned short)keyCode modifierFlags:(NSUInteger)flags target:(id)target action:(SEL)action object:(id)object;

- (DDHotKey *)registerHotKeyWithKeyCode:(unsigned short)keyCode modifierFlags:(NSUInteger)flags task:(DDHotKeyTask)task;
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closure syntax is incorrect. I think you mean the following:

```
hotKeyCenter.registerHotKeyWithKeyCode(34, modifierFlags: 0, task: { _ in
    println("str")
})
```

The `_ in` may be unnecessary if type inference can figure things out, but I suspect you need it. The leading `(NSEvent)` is not proper Swift syntax, however.

Comment: Ah, sorry, thanks a lot. Unfortunately, it doesn't link now -- for some reason it doesn't see symbols like DDHotKeyCenter and gives me an error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDHotKeyCenter"". What could be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: That's an unrelated issue. You're almost certainly failing to link DDHotKeyCenter. If you think you are, describe your situation in a new question (though searching SO for linking objc to swift will probably help you).