# Capture Global Keydown Events (not simply observe)

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

I've created some global hotkeys. However using `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` I can only observe keydown events. What if I want to capture the event and prevent other applications from receiving it?

Here's what I have for *observing* keydown events:

```
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
        func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
            NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(.KeyDownMask, handler: keyDown)
            NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(.KeyDownMask) { (event) -> NSEvent! in
                self.keyDown(event)
                return event
            }
        }
        func keyDown(event : NSEvent) {
            if event.modifierFlags.contains(.ControlKeyMask) && event.modifierFlags.contains(.AlternateKeyMask) && event.modifierFlags.contains(.CommandKeyMask) && event.keyCode == 126 {
                print("⌃⌥⌘↑ pressed")
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure where to start to *capture* keydown events. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid not: "you can only observe the event; you cannot modify or otherwise prevent the event from being delivered to its original target application." source: [NSEvent Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:)

Comment: "Event taps make it possible to monitor and filter input events from several points within the system, prior to their delivery to a foreground application." source: [Quartz Event Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550)

Comment: Thanks @Willeke. I've never attempted anything with the Quartz framework. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DDHotKey](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey) allows you to capture keydown events and use them to trigger function in you app. I discovered it recently in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392155/unable-to-use-objective-c-library-in-swift-project). If you don't already know how to integrate Objective-C code into a Swift project, you can find the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).